PDF Preview of LaTeX does not refresh in VS Code when PDF is used in another program
When I compile a LaTeX file on VS Code, the PDF viewer does not automatically refresh when this file is open in Adobe Acrobat Reader or syncing in Google Drive.
This is despite the PDF file being updated. Is there a way to force the Viewer to refresh?

When the PDF is open i Adobe Reader, the file is locked by AR and other programmes cannot write to it (this is because AR can edit the PDF). There is not much one can do about that. Not sure about what Google Drive does.

use a different viewer, acrobat has always had this problem

@daleif It's wrong that other programs cannot write to it. As I wrote, the PDF is updated, i.e. overwritten. VS Code simply doesn't refresh the viewer.
